# save bitmap as a jpeg file

Tags: android, image

this question is easy,we can :

```
public static void writePhotoJpg(Bitmap data, String pathName) {
    File file = new File(pathName);
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
        // BufferedOutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(
        // new FileOutputStream(file));

        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
        data.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, os);
        os.flush();
        os.close();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but this method not all successful:because "Note: not all Formats support all bitmap configs directly, so it is possible that the returned bitmap from BitmapFactory could be in a different bitdepth, and/or may have lost per-pixel alpha (e.g. JPEG only supports opaque pixels)." in the google document. without luck i have this problem: in the Camera preview i used :

```
 private Bitmap  printScreen() {
    View view = this.getWindow().getDecorView();
    // if (view.isDrawingCacheEnabled()) {
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    String date = c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" + (c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "-" + c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "  " + c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + "-" + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + "-" + c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    // }
    view.buildDrawingCache();

    Bitmap bmp = view.getDrawingCache();

    return  bmp ;
}
```

so when i used setImageBitmap(bmp) ,looks very well,but when i open the save  jpeg file it is a black jpeg.so i think the save method is not well,can you tell me another save method?

Answer (score 3):

you can try this:

```
 public static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 8;
 static void writeExternalToCache(Bitmap bitmap, File file) {
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        final BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, BUFFER_SIZE);
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
        bos.flush();
        bos.close();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }

}
```

it works in my code, so if it's not work, try to find error:

1.the bitmap display right ?

2.where is the bitmap save file? the file has some limit? like size or ...

**if the error is your post reason, you can try decode the bitmap again using `Bitmap.Config.RGB_565`.**

Comment: sorry,no effect.i also using Bitmap.Config.RGB_565

Comment: Excellent! but I have tried several times using this code with failure, cause I was missing one thing...to add this permission into Manifest file: 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.getRootView()` method of view  OR the layout contains this view, use it (e.g.) **mainLayout** contain one image view at index 1 then `mainlayou.getChildAt(1)` to get the view.

E.g.

```
View v1 = mainLayout.getChildAt(1);     //OR  View v1 = mainLayout.getRootView();   
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        return bitmap;
```

Hope helpful to you...

Comment: i have tried and works for me. if i want to take screen shot of particular view and save it as bitmap is possible with this.

Comment: yes,if  used common environment  it correct,but used catch Camera preview it fail,the save file jpeg is black,but imageview show correct